# Which verse in Quran Chapter 2 talks about female sexual pleasure?

Tags: quran, women, sex, husband-wife, wife

This article talks about sexologist Heba Kotb of Egypt. She says: "the biggest chapter of the Quran is called "The Cow." There is a verse talking about the woman's rising pleasure. It's an order to the man to give the woman the right to have pleasure -- it orders the man to give the woman foreplay and also to get the wife to have sex repeatedly and to not wait for the woman to ask because sometimes she's too shy to ask."
https://www.salon.com/2007/06/06/kotb/

Comment: Just read the entire article and you quote from there, why did not she mention the verse number?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in an interpretation "وَقَدِّمُواْ لأَنفُسِكُمْ " in verse [2:223](https://legacy.quran.com/2/223)

> Your wives are a place of sowing of seed for you, so come to your place of cultivation however you wish and **put forth [righteousness] for yourselves**. And fear Allah and know that you will meet Him. And give good tidings to the believers.

قَدِّمُواْ actually means doing something before ... which is interpreted by some scholars as an indication of a foreplay, by others as praying (for example for a newly married couple) or doing good deeds before having intercourse.

The wording of the Qur'an is usually very restrained when it comes to the spousal relationship, but it clearly does neither indicate nor displays any information about a rising female (sexual) pleasure. I'd even say you might not even find any quotes in the sunnah too. So this part is a clear "exaggerated interpretation" of the author of this article.

See also
[What are the virtuous acts of the first night together for newly married spouses?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44352/what-are-the-virtuous-acts-of-the-first-night-together-for-newly-married-spouses/44367#44367)

Answer (score 0):

I think she is inaccurately alluding to Quran 2:223 https://legacy.quran.com/2/223 by referring to a commentary on the verse. Hadith refer to foreplay and to satisfy the wife before than man I believe. Nothing in the verse about female's rising pleasure (orgasm?) but Hadith talk about that.