# How to interpret the hadith Musnad Al-Bazzār 16/215/8628?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, husband-wife, awrah

Assalamu alaykum I read in this hadith
Musnad Al-Bazzār 16/215/8628

> "When one of you goes in unto his wife, let him be covered, for if he is not covered, the angels feel shy and depart, then if they have a child, the Shaytaan will have a share of him."

What does it mean? 
Have a man or woman to stay covered in front of his wife or husband?
Or does it mean only durong the during the sex? Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information on this hadith like narrator chain or on who's authority it was narrated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the hadith you mentioned is among a lot of ahadith which lead to the conclusion that there's a 'awrah between spouses which are all qualified as da'if or worse so one is not recommended to use them as evidence nor to conclude a ruling from them. Another one is that of [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1319970) (which was compiled by al-Bazzar on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn Mas'oud -see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=291&hid=1530&pid=134993), but includes Mundil ibn 'Ali  مِنْدَلُ بْنُ عَلِيٍّ  a rejected narrator in the chain) you may read more in the linked fatwa.

Note that al-Bazzar (see [here](http://islamport.com/l/mtn/1145/8477.htm)) already considered it as da'if saying:

> وإسناده ليس بالقوي

which means that the narrator chain has some weaknesses, it was also compilled by imam at-Tabarani in his [al-Majma' al-Awsat](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=85&bookhad=178), and quoted by abu Bakr al-Haythami in [Majma' az-Zawa'id](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=87&ID=7574) where he considered the narrator whom at-Tabarni himself pointed at the fact that he is the only source narrating this "Yahya ibn Ayub يحيى بن أيوب", as unknown which is a clear weakness in the narrator chain. Both al-Bazzar and at-Tabarani are compiling the hadith on the authority of abu Hurrairah via approximately the same chain and the only different narrators are trustworthy.

The wording used is:

> إذا **أتى** أحدُكم أهله ...

Which was also translated if one intends to have sexual intercourse in this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1445) others translated it more literally when having intercourse. Both meanings are valid because you may have intercourse directly or you may consider the foreplay as part of the intercourse for the second option and this way one can find an explanation for both meanings. As foreplay is considered as part of the act of intercourse if one has in mind that it is decreed in the Qur'an(See for example [Which verse in Quran Chapter 2 talks about female sexual pleasure?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/which-verse-in-quran-chapter-2-talks-about-female-sexual-pleasure/)).

"[أتى](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A3%D8%AA%D9%89/)" literally means came or came to or arrive or does one could also add the interpret it goes to.

Note that the majority of scholars say there's no 'awrah between spouses, but one should fear and respect Allah and the angels which are around us, so walking around nakedly if nobody sees you is something which might be allowed, but one shouldn't do and so spouses should keep this to the necessary minimum.
So the answer of your question is that being naked in front of your spouses per se is halal, but it shouldn't be practiced in an exaggerated manner and you also could be more or less naked while having intercourse or even foreplay, if you both feel at ease.
In a hadith compilled by at-Tabarani in his [al-Mo'jam al-Kabir](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=477&hid=8235&pid=285315), 'Othman ibn Madh'on -a sahabi()- said to the prophet () that he feels shy if his wife (or wives) would see his 'awrah, the prophet answered why do you feel so if Allah made you both a clothing for eachother... this is a reference to the words of the Qur'an:

> ... They are clothing for you and you are clothing for them.  ... ([2:187](https://legacy.quran.com/2/187))

which are about intercourse between spouses in the nights of Ramadan!
This hadith is marfo' and has some weaknesses as it is also questionable whether or not is mursal. But a better evidence and its explanation can be found in my answer on [What did Abu Dawud mean by "nakarah" in regards to the strong awrahness of the thigh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37135/what-did-abu-dawud-mean-by-nakarah-in-regards-to-the-strong-awrahness-of-the-t/37390#37390)

You may also refer to the fatwa islamqa [#45514](https://islamqa.info/en/45514).

See also: [What is the 'awrah between husbands and wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/what-is-the-awrah-between-husbands-and-wives).

If I found time I might search for some additional information based on commentaries of similar ahadith if I found anymore input.

Comment: assalamu alaykum. I'd need a clarification.In the question In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?" you answered, between the other things, about the humble group opinion..."You should not look at your women organs if there is no need even during sex". What they  mean about female oragns? Only the vagina or also the breast? Thank you! @Medi1Saif

Comment: @Hamza I don't know which question or answer you refer to, but the context of the ahadith seems to lead to the interpretation that the organs refer to the vagina.

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple @Medi1Saif

Comment: @Hamza that's not an answer of mine! I've just commented there no more nor less.

Comment: assalamu alaykum. I'd need a clarification.In the question In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?" you answered, between the other things, about the humble group opinion..."You should not look at your women organs if there is no need even during sex". What they mean about female oragns? Only the vagina or also the breast? Thank you! @muslim1

Comment: assalamu alaycum, in the question https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple there is written " In case of intercourse, a woman may just allow his man organ "...what does it mean? That a woman can't to see the husband body during the intercourses or it refers at oral sex?

Comment: @Hamza I have no idea I'm not the author of that answer, so why are you asking me? A remark: at least in my posts you may find a lot of typos.

Comment: It is said that a couple should have to cover with a sheet during the intercourses. But can husband see the brest wife during the foreplays, for exempe to to kiss them? Exuse me so much, but I m going to be crazy...I feel very sick for these doubts @Medi1Saif

Comment: @Hamza when the majority says that you maybe totally uncovered in front of your spouse and almost all scholars agree that hiding the 'awrah is more likely to be a matter of respect in this case, what makes you sick? I mean if you are legally married it is your right to see your wife naked -if she agrees- so what hinders you from all of this? As long as the cover is on top of both of you and nobody can see you and the time is adequate etc. everything is fine.

Comment: so, can the blanket be on top of both and not between them? excuse me so much!

Comment: @Hamza Yes assuming they are married, both agree and the time for this is adequate, note that some people feel shy to be naked in front of others so it is possible that a wife or husband refuses. The blanket should be on top of both as if anybody enters the room for example small children ... they shouldn't see the 'awrah of their parents etc.

Comment: Salam alaykum How is to interpretate this hadith: "The Prophet died; he never looked at me (private parts) and I nevere loooked at his"? What does "private parts" mean in thise case? Only the genitals or also the breast? Jazakallauh khayra. I m sorry I mvery anxsous for these doubds...Ramadan kareem

Comment: ♦ Oct 17 '18 at 8:29
Salam alaykum How is to interpretate this hadith: "The Prophet died; he never looked at me (private parts) and I nevere loooked at his"? What does "private parts" mean in thise case? Only the genitals or also the breast? Jazakallauh khayra. I m sorry very anxoous forvtgese doubds. @Medi1Saif

Comment: @Hamza I never heard anybody calling the breasts the private parts. It is obvious what is meant here.

Comment: assalam alaykum. You wrote in a question that I did about one years ago that "...hiding awra is a me a question of respect in more lukely a form of respect in this case...". What do you mind? Awrah is every the body for the women. So I don't hunderstand. Did you mean only the genitals or also the breast?  And what do you mind for respect? To whom? Is it possible to look the wife nude only under the sheet? Excuse me so much for every these question but I m very anxsious and sad for every these dubts and these not clear rules. I m living a period of strong depression for this cause.

Comment: @Hamza I wonder if you understand English at all. And I don't know what you understand from the given answer or not as all information is in there and I doubt if something might be unclear to anybody else, but you. The meaning of 'awrah differs depending on the relationship and situation. We are here discussing the case of a married couple.